# Help me understand why my solution to this combinatorics problem is incorrect.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question:

> In how many ways a team of 11 players can be selected out of 15 players such that 2 particular players never come together in a team.

My solution:

No of ways = No of ways which p1 is excluded + No of ways in which p2 is excluded - No of ways in which both p1 and p2 are excluded
Formulas used-
No of ways of exluding p particular objects in the selection =C(n-p,r)
So,  no of ways = C(15-1,11)+C(15-1,11)-(15-2,11)
On calculating answer turns out to be 650 while the actual answer is 1794.
What has gone wrong here ?

Comment: Have you considered calculating the number of ways that the two players can be on a team together?

Comment: Is the answer in your book correct for sure, because there are only $\binom{15}{11}=1365$ teams total excluding nobody which is less than $1794$

Comment: Have you given us the exact text of the question? Sometimes, provided answers are wrong. Sometimes, we are answering the wrong question. As you've stated the question, the given answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank for ur help I think the answer given in book is wrong.  Btw how can we calculate no of ways where both players are together.

Comment: Looks like (in your book) someone tried to calculate $\binom{13}{10}$ by hand but forgot to divide by $3$. It is meant to be $\frac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}=286$ but you have $\frac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11}{1\cdot 2}=858$. To me it looks like a human error.

Comment: And, yes, number of ways when both are together is $\binom{15-2}{11-2}=\binom{13}{9}=715$ as we are picking $9$ remaining candidates from the pool of $13$ remaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your answer is correct and your book (or teacher) has made a mistake. I calculated the same result by taking the number of total teams and subtracting the number of teams that include both players by doing
$$
\binom{15}{11}-\binom{13}{9}=650
$$
Also the total number of possible teams is $\binom{15}{11}=1365<1794$ which doesn't make sense

Comment: +1, But don't rule out the possibility that OP is misreading the question. Yes, the given answer is wrong for the given question, but OP should also make sure that they are giving us the exact question, as given, not their version of it.